# Bootstrap 4 beta carousel indicators and controls not responding to mouse click

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap carousels. I copied the html code from Bootstrap 4 Beta documentation and linked css, js from maxcdn. The carousel loads perfectly and images slide and even pause on mouse hover. However the indicators and the prev/next controls do not respond to mouse clicks. Please help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">


 <title>Carousel</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="5"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="images/011.jpg" alt="One" class="d-block img-fluid">
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="images/012.jpg" alt="Two" class="d-block img-fluid">
   </div>    
   <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="images/013.jpg" alt="Three" class="d-block img-fluid">
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="images/014.jpg" alt="Four" class="d-block img-fluid">
   </div>    
   <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="images/015.jpg" alt="Five" class="d-block img-fluid">
   </div>    
   <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="images/016.jpg" alt="Six" class="d-block img-fluid">
   </div>        
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
 </div>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the data-target and href attributes always points to the id of your class="carousel-slide" which in your case is myCarousel.
In class="carousel-indicators" set data-target= "#myCarousel" and in class="carousel-control-prev" and class="carousel-control-next" set href="#myCarousel" for it to work.